# Duplicated rows when merging on pandas

Tags: pandas, merge, rows

I have a list that contains multiple pandas dataframes.

Each dataframe has columns 'Trading Day' and Maturity.
However the name of the column Maturity changes depending on the maturity, for example the first dataframe column names are: 'Trading Day', 'Y_2021','Y_2022'.

The second dataframe has 'Trading Day',Y_2022','Y_2023','Y_2024'.

The column 'Trading day' has all unique np.datetime64 dates for every dataframe
And the maturity columns have either floats or nans

My goal is to merge all the dataframes into one and have something like:
'Trading Day','Y_2021,'Y_2022','Y_2023',...'Y_2030'

In my code gh is the list that contains all the dataframes and original is a dataframe that contains all the dates from 5 years ago through today.

gt is the final dataframe.

So far what I have done is:

```
original = pd.DataFrame()
original['Trading Day'] = np.arange(np.datetime64(str(year_now-5)+('-01-01')), np.datetime64(date.today())+1)

for i in range(len(gh)):
    gh[i]['Trading Day']=gh[i]['Trading Day'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
    
gt = pd.merge(original,gh[0],on='Trading Day',how = 'left')

for i in range (1,len(gh)):
    gt=pd.merge(gt,gh[i],how='outer')
```

The code works more or less the problem is that when there is a change of years I get the following example results:

```
           Y_2021     Y_2023    Y_2024
2020-06-05  45          
2020-06-05              54
2020-06-05                       43
2020-06-06  34    
2020-06-06              23
2020-06-06                       34

#While what I want is:

           Y_2021     Y_2023    Y_2024
2020-06-05  45          54       43
2020-06-06  34          23       34
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your actual output and what you want, you should be able to just:

```
output.ffill().bfill().drop_duplicates()
```

To get the output you want.

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix:

```
gt = gt.groupby('Trading Day').sum()
gt = gt.replace(0, np.nan)
```